# VBA macro : find button by location and 'click' them

Tags: vba, excel, button

I'm trying to du a macro. From a row index and a column index detect if there is one or more button on this cell and execute the code attached to this button.

I have not found a 'find_button_by_location' method nor a 'button.execute_as_clicked'

I wonder if anyone can help me with some suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: A button is a control.  You will not search for them by cell for position, more traditionally you will cycle through the objects on your worksheet and look for certain names, if you are looking for a particular button.  Buttons do not have a depressed or not "state" in VBA, when you click one it calls an event, that event is <button name>_click, so rather than bother to click the button for a user, you instead call it's button_click sub/function.  Make sense?  You need to post some code that you have attempted to create a button and act upon it.

Comment: You don't want to be randomly executing button code. You want to be sure of what code you are executing and therefore target  buttons. Hold the buttons in variables and use those.

Comment: @JarBeans: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: I Downvoted/voted to close because you didn't include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) , it looks like [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work for you:

```
Sub ClickButton(ByVal arg_rCells As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim oOLE As OLEObject
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim hButtons As Object

    Set ws = arg_rCells.Parent
    Set hButtons = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'ActiveX buttons
    For Each oOLE In ws.OLEObjects
        hButtons.Add oOLE.Name, oOLE.Name
        If Not Intersect(arg_rCells, ws.Range(oOLE.TopLeftCell, oOLE.BottomRightCell)) Is Nothing Then
            Run "'" & ws.Parent.Name & "'!" & ws.CodeName & "." & oOLE.Name & "_Click"
        End If
    Next oOLE

    'Form Control buttons
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Not hButtons.exists(shp.Name) Then
            hButtons.Add shp.Name, shp.Name
            If Not Intersect(arg_rCells, ws.Range(shp.TopLeftCell, shp.BottomRightCell)) Is Nothing Then
                Run shp.OnAction
            End If
        End If
    Next shp

End Sub
```

And here's an example of how to call it (this will click a button if one exists in cell C3):

```
Sub tgr()

    ClickButton ActiveSheet.Range("C3")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @tigeravatar it really help me and now I have a better understanding of how it works.